# Generate random number and push into array without repeat

Tags: java, android

How can I generate random number and push into array without repeat, in Android Studio? I  need to generate numbers between 1 and 30. Thanks

Comment: Use a hashset or a treeset instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        while(list.size() != 30) {
            list.add((int)(Math.random()*30+1));
        }
        List<Integer> randomlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        Collections.shuffle(randomlist);
        int[] arr = new int[30];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = randomlist .get(i);
```

or

```
        int[] arr = new int[30];
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i ++)
            list.add(i);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = list.get(i);
```

Comment: Why are you using a hashmap instead of just a hashset?